# Cartesian equation of a line parallel to the X-axis in 3D

Tags: vectors, 3d

Suppose the vector equation of a line parallel to the X-axis is

```
x = 1 + t
y = 2
z = 3
```

How do I rewrite this into a cartesian equation like the below example?

```
ƛ = x + 1 = 1 - y = z - 1
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You cannot express a line in 3d space as a cartesian equation.

Answer (score 0):

A line in 3-D space cannot be expressed as a cartesian equation the way it could be expressed in 2-D space.

Take for example 1-D space. Suppose we have $x=1$. We just have one point, $(1)$. Next, go into 2-D space, and $x=1$ is a vertical line, and no longer a point (since any $y$-value will satisfy $x=1$. Then, move into 3-D space, where $x=1$ is a plane, since any $z,y$-values will satisfy $x=1$.